# Selection is lost if you scroll beyond the grids buffer zone

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6-classic

Selection is lost if you scroll beyond the grids buffer zone (5 pages default).

Steps to reproduce:

1. select any item from the first page
2. scroll through each cached page until a new set of pages are loaded (scroll to pass the buffer zone) - default 5 pages
3. **selection is lost** (see button label - "Selected (0)" )

extjs version: 6.7.0

see [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/32gr)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the documentation of [BufferedStore](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/classic/Ext.data.BufferedStore.html). 
The last paragraph states the following:

> Selection state may be maintained across page boundaries by
>   configuring the SelectionModel not to discard records from its
>   collection when those Records cycle out of the Store's primary
>   collection. This is done by configuring the SelectionModel like this:
>
> ```
> selModel: {
>     pruneRemoved: false
> }
> ```

You could either add this to your store, or your grid configuration.